# Background Image not displaying in nav

Tags: css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I just can't figure out as to why my background image isn't showing in on the top right corner of my navbar. The mobile view brings up the image but my desktop view is drawing a blank. FYI, I am using the wp starter theme, FoundationPress. Any guidance would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
<div class="inner-wrap">
  <?php do_action('foundationPress_layout_start'); ?>
      <nav class="tab-bar show-for-small-only">
        <section class="right-small">
          <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
        </section>
          <section class="middle tab-bar-section">
             <!--  Top right logo mobile-->
               <a href="#">
                  <div class="title logo"></div><!-- This one shows up on mobile view-->
               </a>
          </section>
      </nav>

      <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
        <?php foundationPress_mobile_off_canvas(); ?>
      </aside>

    <div class="top-bar-container contain-to-grid show-for-medium-up">
        <nav class="top-bar">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name"><a href="#" class="m-desk-logo"></a> <!--  This doesn't show up on desktop view-->
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <?php foundationPress_top_bar_l(); ?>
                <?php foundationPress_top_bar_r(); ?>
            </section>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.m-desk-logo {
    background: url("../assets/img/main-nav-cwk-carrot-logo.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
     width: 100%;
}
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/buwotaca/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I would suggest adding a JSFiddle to this so we can work directly with your code.

Comment: I can't immediately see anything wrong with your html and css but if you could put it in a jsfiddle or something similar, it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Will do, I am setting it up now. Thanks.

Comment: @MannfromReno I couldn't figure out how to get it up in jsfiddle but put it in jsbin instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Jay Put the link at the bottom. Thanks, Jay!

Comment: Could it just be that it's never loading the Desktop sized theme at all? As far as your code looks currently you make no mention of viewport. For example add this to your head <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: @Doug Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't want to post all my code so I just posted the nav part. The viewport is in there but always good reminder :). I'll have to post an <img> tag with the logo in there for now.

Comment: `m-desk-logo` class is no where in the html ?

Comment: @nolawipetros It's in there. look for <li class="name"><a href="#" class="m-desk-logo"></a> <!--  This doesn't show up on desktop view-->

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in jsbin.
Press Shift+F5 (clears your cache).

Comment: Tried that but thank you for the suggestion. Still no luck. Specificity might be blocking the image from showing? I'll post the solution when I get it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

ok its working for me if i change a [few things around](http://jsbin.com/buwotaca/4)

on css

```
.m-desk-logo {
background-size: 100px;
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
}
```

on the html there is no need to add a span inside the a

```
<li  class="name m-desk-logo"><a href="#"></a>
```

background-size contain is only working if you set a height and width! part of the issue was that the li was not overflowing for some reason....

Answer (score 0):

make span a block element to able to see the background img

```
.m-desk-logo {
   background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/20/Ursus_maritimus_us_fish.jpg) no-repeat;
   height:45px;
   display:block;
}
```